# Пустой репозиторий и содержимое папки .git

Tags: linux, git, github

Так как я обычный пользователь, то Github использую только на уровне `git clone *`. Нашел, к примеру, маленькую утилиту, прочел описание; понравилась — качаю исходники, если нужно — компилирую, пользуюсь. Тут все понятно.

Но столкнулся я с такой проблемой. Когда скачиваешь утилиту и заходишь в ее каталог, там нет ничего кроме файла `README` (на первый взгляд). Если мы введем команду `ls -all` то обнаружим скрытые папку `.git` и файл `.gitignore`.
В папке `.git` будут следующие каталоги и файлы:

> branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  index  info  logs  objects  packed-refs  refs

Я не понимаю, что со всем этим делать и что это вообще такое. Разъясните, пожалуйста, как этим пользоваться? Как собрать программу из этого всего, чтобы все работало?

Comment: Вам придется переписать вопрос. Приведите пример. Укажите адрес репозитория. Опишите, что вы хотели получить, что уже получили, что не удалось.

Comment: @Стёпа В директории `.git` "мозги" git-а - все манипуляции и их история с этой [VCS](https://goo.gl/2YrASq) хранятся там. Файл .gitignore позволяет задавать правила, в соответствии с которыми будут игнорироваться отдельные папки/файлы проекта. Данные "артефакты" являются служебными. Если вы не собираетесь продолжить разработку данного проекта, то можете смело их удалять.

Answer (score 2):

Содержимое папки .git - это, собственно, репозиторий. Не ищите в нем ваших файлов, их там не может быть. Там собственная структура хранения данных, похожая на юниксовую файловую систему.

.gitignore - это список файлов (заданный в форме регулярных выражений), которые гит будет игнорировать.

Программу из этого не собрать никак. Читайте readme, как уже выше сказано. Также вы можете посмотреть на wiki-страницы соответствующего репозитория на гитхабе.

Есть небольшой шанс, что всё было удалено одним из последних комментов, как подсказывает @KoVadim. В таком случае выполните `git log` чтобы посмотреть, что там раньше происходило. Можно также взять SHA-код какого-нибудь из предыдущих коммитов (это длинная строка вроде abcd1234) и сделать `git diff abcd1234`.

Comment: "Не ищите в нем ваших файлов, их там не может быть" - это не так. Все файлы хранятся в папке `.git`. Но искать их там не стоит, это правда.

Comment: можно попробовать выполнить git log и посмотреть. Может там последним коммитом все удалили. Тогда можно будет "отмотать историю" и получить сорцы.

Comment: Ну они там хранятся в форме блобов, которые никак не прочитать вручную.

Comment: смотря, что понимать под словом "вручную". git show <sha1> - это вручную или нет?

Comment: git show <sha1> - это все-таки вооруженным глазом нашли. Тем более, что нужный sha1 надо будет где-то найти.

Comment: а не нужно его искать. Более того, даже знать. git log все сам расскажет.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вы склонировали репозиторий, в котором в дефолтной ветке кроме README ничего нет. Почитайте README, возможно в нем будут какие-то намеки на то, где взять исходники.